# GML and JPEG2000 library

Tags: c++, xml, gml, jpeg2000

have you ever worked with JPEG2000 and/or GML?. 
I'm reading documentation about GMLJP2 but I don't find any libraries that implement this. I mean, as far as I know it should be possible to have a GML file within a jp2 file (that is, a single file with both of the thigs).
Also, it's difficult to get a viewer that integrates GML and JPEG2000.

Any information regarding how to work with GML or JPEG200 is wellcome ;-)

Many thanks!

PD: I want to work with C or C++ but it doesn't matter the language yet

Answer (score 0):

"Also, it's difficult to get a viewer that integrates GML and JPEG2000."

As I understand GML is just a block of metadata in XML inserted into JPEG2000 file. Any decent decoder should be able to extract it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a JP2 metadata editor and included basic GML support.

You can download it here:

http://j2k-codec.com/mde.html

See the "gml.jp2" file for an example.

Hope it will be helpful.